# mysql to html display values for the same value column

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I'm having trouble to get the right output. I have a table like this:

[image: table]

I'm using the following PHP code to create the table:

```
<?php 
include_once("includes/dbh.inc.php");
if(isset($_POST["r_id"])){
    $output = '';

    $query = "SELECT * FROM relatorioc WHERE datas = '".$_POST["r_id"]."'";
    $res = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    $output .='
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered">';

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){                
            $output .= '
                `<tr>
                    <td>'.$row['linha'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['user'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['prob'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['res'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['timep'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['timei'].'</td>
                </tr>';
        }
        $output .= "</table></div>";
        echo $output;    
}
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Hint: `$data = []; while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){ $data[$row['linha']][] = $row; } var_export($data)`

Comment: Ok i can see all  data on the $data but how do i use the data i want? because my objective is to build tables with the title of "linha" and populate it with the associate values.

Comment: I'm almost there right now i have this in my table:

Linha

data from the first "linha"

Linha

data from the second "linha"

The problem is that is just showing one row for each linha i want to show all the row that each "Linha" have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before I answer your question it's important for you to be aware of your aobvious security hole in your code, which is a [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection): you don't escape input before entering to the SQL query. (`$_POST["r_id"]`)

Now for your question, all I did is making an array, and in the while loop I enter the rows grouped by "linha", then outputing using two `foreach`. I also escaped the input for you, in the SQL query. (`mysqli_real_escape_string`)

```
if (isset($_POST["r_id"])) {
    $output = '';

    $query = "SELECT * FROM relatorioc WHERE datas = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["r_id"]) . "'";
    $res = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    $data = [];

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
        $data[$row['linha']][] = $row;
    }

    $output .= '';

    foreach ($data as $linha => $items) {
        $output .= '<p>' . $linha . '</p>';
        $output .= '
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered">';

        foreach ($items as $row) {
            $output .= '
            <tr>
                <td>' . $row['linha'] . '</td>
                <td>' . $row['user'] . '</td>
                <td>' . $row['prob'] . '</td>
                <td>' . $row['res'] . '</td>
                <td>' . $row['timep'] . '</td>
                <td>' . $row['timei'] . '</td>
            </tr>';
        }

        $output .= '</table></div>';
    }

    echo $output;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much!! and if i want to add the date as a header for each linha? can i make two while loops?

Comment: @AlexandreAlves what do you mean? do you want to write some date next to the "linha" title? or do you want to group by date instead of "linha"?

Answer (score -1):

You need make first 'group by' query and before make other with col grouped, if not have You to many Mysql experience, also others more compicated queries is possible.

(group by 'linha' in first query and before other with where (first resul are ='linha' value)

select * from relatorioc datas = '".$_POST["r_id"]."'"; group by 'linha' 
before :
 $query = "SELECT * FROM relatorioc WHERE datas = '".$_POST["r_id"]."'" and linha= 'previous result';

This is easy solution for You.

Comment: Can you explain better? you  mean $query2 = "SELECT * FROM relatorioc GROUP BY linha";
        $res2 = mysqli_query($conn, $query2);

        $query = "SELECT * FROM relatorioc WHERE datas = '".$_POST["r_id"]." AND linha = '$res2'";
        $res = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

Comment: You first make :

Answer (score -2):

first make a query grouping the results according to your needs to do this ->:

```
select * from relatorioc datas = '". $ _ POST [" r_id "]."' "; group by 'linha' with it will provide the necessary data to the following query ->: $ query = "SELECT * FROM relatoryc WHERE datas = '". $ _ POST ["r_id"]. "'" and linha = 'previous result';
```